# Parsing json file with an unconventional token

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I have a json file with the following format:

```
 [{   "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
            "name" : "john",
            "code" : "01",
            "address" : "10 street",
            "emailDomain" : "email@example.com"  
}]
```

I am not able to parse it for further processing as java ee says the "objectid" is not recognised. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Java is searching for definition of 'objectid'.. Is this json object defined in same file? Moreover as Matt has indicated in below answer, this doesn't make a valid json.

Comment: @RahulWinner There is a json file which contains above data. I want to parse it for building database...

Comment: I could not get your point. The 'objectid' definition is missing. Looks like you copied this snippet from some javascript code which might be having a function with name "ObjectId".. Please check..

Answer (score 2):

[**This is not valid JSON**](http://jsonlint.com/), plain and simple. How can you expect to parse invalid input?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fix your JSON before you can parse it properly. As Matt has show, your JSON is invalid and will result in errors. Your options are to fix whatever is outputting the JSON to output it properly OR write a script to fix your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a JSON file can only be [primitive type](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Variables_and_Types) in JavaScript. For that ObjectId("123") value, you could convert it to a String (possibly using toString() function) before having parser parse it.